# How does wso2 am keystore and client-truststore work in distribution development?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have configured a distributed API-M deployment with traffic manager separation.
Envirmonents:

```
There were three nodes to run profile:
vm1, cp.wso2.com, Control Plane
vm2, gw.wso2.com, API Gateway 
vm3, tm.wso2.com, Traffic Manager
```

I got self-signed certificate for each node , and imported them to client-truststore.jks

Two main error logs in gw console:

```
1.Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://tm.wso2.com:9711

2.PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.Sun
CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

And cp console also had errors like:

```
AMQConnectionFailureException: Could not open connection
```

I don't know what i miss?

Comment: Based on the error, it seems the cert is not available. Are you having the updated client-truststore.jks in all the nodes?

Comment: Yes, I updated client-truststore.jks for each node, I did below:
step1,  got self-signed certificate by keytool with running command:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in tm.wso2.com.cert -inkey tm.wso2.com.key -name "newcert" -out pfskeystore.pfx
 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore pfskeystore.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore newkeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

Comment: step3, convert the PKCS12/PFX formatted keystore to a Java keystore using the following command:
#keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore pfskeystore.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore newkeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

step4, export the public key from my  newkeystore.jks file using the following command:
#keytool -export -alias newcert -keystore newkeystore.jks -file newcert.pem

Comment: step5, import the public key  extracted in the previous step to the client-truststore.jks file using the following command:
#keytool -import -alias newcert -file newcert.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon

Comment: I got self-signed certificate for each node with:
vm1, cp.wso2.com.cert/ cp.wso2.com.key
vm2, gw.wso2.com.cert/ gw.wso2.com.key 
vm3, tm.wso2.com.cert tm.wso2.com.key
And  did the same step1 - step5 above for each node with there own client-truststore.jks and newkeystore.jks, and then, i configed jks in deployment for each node :
[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "newkeystore.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "123456"
alias =  "newcert"
key_password =  "123456"

Comment: Can you try without changing the keystore file name?

Comment: Yes, i did.  I import my cert into default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) and client-truststore.jks, but it doesn't work.  I can access publisher and devportal , but it fails when invoking api